# Not able to predict the cluster membership of a new point under hdbscan function available under "dbscan" package

Tags: cluster-analysis, prediction, predict, hierarchical-clustering, hdbscan

I am using hdbscan function under the package called "dbscan" to perform clustering on a data. I am not able to predict the membership of a new data point after the cluster is built. The predict function works for the object built under dbscan function but it is not working for hdbscan. The error is: 
"Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "hdbscan""

**Any suggestion?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no predict method. In HDBSCAN there is a `approximate_predict()` function.

How this works you can check more on the documentation.